# Using ng-click functions in other functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In Angular I have an `ng-click` functions `ng-click="create()"` and `ng-click="detect()"`

These work when ran on their own, but what if I wanted to run `ng-click="detect()"` inside `ng-click="create()"`

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.create = function () {
};

$scope.detect = function () {
};
```

Comment: this question is unclear. What does runing `ng-click="detect()"` inside `ng-click="create()"` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do:

```
$scope.create = function () {
    $scope.detect();
};
```